# how to enable the ssl support for the current python 2.7.3 on opensuse 12.3?

Tags: python, ssl, openssl, opensuse

I just use the opensuse 12.3 box from vagrant hub,

unfortunately the installed python 2.7.3 is not support ssl,

so what's the easiest method to enable the ssl support for current python version?

the open ssl devel package libopenssl-devel-1.0.1e-1.1.1.x86_64 is installed.

I know rebuild the python source is ok for enable ssl support,

but when rebuild the python, there are many other dependency issue.

so, I want use the binary installation which already support ssl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems missing one package.

After install the package python-2.7.3-10.20.1.x86_64.rpm, the problem is fixed.

and from the [official web](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/26990223/dir/opensuse_12.x/com/python-2.7.3-10.20.1.x86_64.rpm.html), this package provide the `_ssl.so()(64bit)` support.